# How to capitalize the parameters that are passed in the URL to whatsapp api web?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I would like to capitalize the parameters I pass in the url to whatsapp api web.

Specifically I have the following **href**:

`href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone={{str_replace(' ', '',$client->telephone_number)}}&text=Hello {{ $client->name }} {{ $client->surname }}, I'm trying to send you a message"`

Specifically, I would like `{{ $client->name }} {{ $client->surname }}` capitalized, for example if I have `{{$client->name}}` which is **Mary** and `{{$client->surname}}` which is **Rossi**, I would like to have **MARY ROSSI**.

I have been browsing the internet for some time, but I have not found anything about it.

Could anyone kindly help me?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of PHP `strtoupper()` function which converts a string to uppercase

So change your code to this:

```
href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone={{str_replace(' ', '',$client->telephone_number)}}&text=Hello {{ strtoupper($client->name) }} {{ strtoupper($client->surname) }}, I'm trying to send you a message"
```